# change the borders color and divider item color in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, saas

I using ionic and i need to change some styles on my project. especially i need to change the **borders color** to become red and the **background for divider item list**

"look at the image to understand what i need"
[image]

this is the code for the template page

```
<ion-view title="Home">
<ion-content  scroll="true" class="padding has-header">
    <form class="list">
        <label class="item item-select" name="choose your category">
            <span class="input-label">choose your category</span>
            <select></select>
        </label>
    </form>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-divider">Unreturned stuff</ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left">
            <img>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Item</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-divider">Limited stuff</ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left">
            <img>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Item</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-divider">Skills</ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left">
            <img>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Item</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: do you have working jsfiddle?

Comment: no :( if you need i will upload my files

Comment: So start by looking at the `item-divider` class. Either change it there, or add your own with a background-color: blah !important;

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color of the border of the list by overriding the following classes:

```
.item, .item-divider {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Note however, that this will change the borders of both the items and the dividers and will not achieve exactly what you are describing. If you want some of the borders to stay gray, then you would need to style individual sections of the borders separately using `border-bottom`, `border-left`, `border-right` and `border-top`.

---

To change the background of the dividers using the default colors of Ionic, you need to add the following:

```
<ion-item class="item-divider positive-bg light">Unreturned stuff</ion-item>
```

This adds a blue (positive) background with white (light) text to the divider, however I would recommend creating a custom CSS class that sets a `background-color` and a `color`, like so:

```
.custom-class-divider {
    color: [something];
    background-color: [something else]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change it with the help of

```
ion-item{
   --border-color: rgb(48, 66, 94);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`--border-color` should work according to the documentation but it doesn't do any changes even if `!important` is added

Comment: please do not answer to other answers, as the order of answers may change, or answers may even be deleted in the future. Always answer the original question, or write a comment to an answer.